# How can I reduce the gaps between objects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

At the top :

```
[Range(10, 100)]
public int gap = 10;
private int oldGapValue = 0;
```

And in Update :

```
private void Update()
    {
        if(gap > oldGapValue)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < numberOfUnits; i++)
            {
                units[i].transform.position = (i + 1f) * new Vector3(gap, 0, 0);
            }

            oldGapValue = gap;
        }
        else
        {

        }
```

This working for adding gaps. but in the else part I want to reduce the gaps between the objects.

I tried this but this is not working good, now it's working fine when reducing the gaps but now when adding gaps it's not working good it's adding gaps but also double the units objects until I stop adding gaps it's all stuttering.

```
if(gap > oldGapValue)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < numberOfUnits; i++)
            {
                units[i].transform.position = (i + 1f) * new Vector3(gap, 0, 0);
            }

            oldGapValue = gap;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfUnits; i++)
            {
                units[i].transform.position = (i + 1f) * new Vector3(-gap, 0, 0);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to space objects, by the value of `gap`, every single frame because of your logic.

Might I suggest a different approach and only change the object spacing when the value of `gap` actually changes. As an example, try this code:

```
    [SerializeField]
    [Range ( 10f, 100f )]
    private float _gap = 10f;
    private float _oldGap = 10f;

    public float gap
    {
        get => _gap;
        set
        {
            _oldGap = _gap;
            Debug.Log ( $"New Gap Value {_gap}" );

            for ( int i = 0; i < units.Length; i++ )
            {
                units [ i ].transform.position = new Vector3 ( (gap * i) + 1f, 0, 0 );
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnValidate ( )
    {
        if ( _gap != _oldGap )
            gap = _gap;
    }
```

Comment: There is one problem.  When I'm running the game the unit/s are first starting at some position but once I'm adding gaps first time it's first changing the unit/s position and then adding removing gaps. but why it's first changing it's position and not adding/removing the gaps at it's start position ?

Comment: I tried this in the loop but this is not working good. units[i].transform.position = new Vector3(units[i].transform.position.x + (gap * i), units[i].transform.position.y, units[i].transform.position.z);

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't understand what you're trying to achieve. Would an image help illustrate the point?